Error linking files with wam-ld when linking c executable
I'm trying to compile librdkafka into wasm binary. I executed following commands but on the second line, wasm-ld does not find pthread related symbols.
emcmake cmake -H. -B_cmake_build
cmake --build _cmake_build

[ 34%] Linking C executable producer.js
wasm-ld: error: ../src/librdkafka.a(rdkafka.c.o): undefined symbol: pthread_kill
wasm-ld: error: ../src/librdkafka.a(rdkafka.c.o): undefined symbol: pthread_kill

I tried several ways to inject -pthread flag to the linker, but faced the same error. Below is several commands I have tried

emcmake cmake -H. -B_cmake_build -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-lpthread"
emcmake cmake -H. -B_cmake_build -DCFLAGS="-lpthread"
LDFLAGS="-pthread" cmake --build _cmake_build 


Try building in verbose mode to see what the linker command is. Also try -pthread instead of -lpthread. And CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.

After some research I found it's EMCC_CFLAGS.
EMCC_CFLAGS="-pthread" cmake --build _cmake_build
https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#environment-variables
